# javascript function is not recognized as javascript code

Tags: karate

I have the following javascript file MyService.js:

```
function(config) {

config.MyService = function(request) {
        return call('classpath:path/to/my.feature@tag', request);
    };

return config;
}
```

I load this js from my karate-config.js in order to reuse it from my feature files.

```
config = karate.callSingle('classpath:path/to/MyService.js', config);
```

It works as expected and I can call my.feature from any feature file. For example:

```
Given def res = call MyService myRequest
```

The problem appears when I try to add a new level to MyService.js function:

```
function(config) {

config.ApiOauthService = {
    myCall : function(request) {
        return call('classpath:path/to/my.feature@tag', request);
    }
};


return config;
}
```

When I add the following code to my feature file:

```
Given def myCall = call MyService.myCall myRequest
```

I get the following error: "not a js function or feature file"

Do anybody know where is the problem? Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in Karate 0.9.3 onwards we have limited JS function nesting to only the top-level. You can find a full explanation in [this comment](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/821#issuecomment-509172370).

So if you need JS function "name spacing" you can easily achieve this as per the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file

And if you need more complex nesting, switch to using Java code where you can nest functions at any level.